# Configurar PHPMAILER 6.0.1

Tags: phpmailer

Galera,estava usando o phpmailer 5.x.x para enviar e-mails (usando o gmail) pelo meu site. Funcionava perfeitamente.
Recentemente sofremos alguns ataques devido a problemas de segurança desta versão. Então preciso atualizar para a versão 6.

Não consigo achar nada que me ajude a configurar o servidor corretamente. Todos tutoriais que eu acho são para versões anteriores. Será que alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 1):

Essa é versão mais recente do *PHPMailer*, lançada dia 14 de Setembro, a [documentação](http://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/) está disponível em Inglês, também há alguns exemplos disponível no repositório no [github](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/tree/master/examples), aonde você encontrará dois exemplos de como integrar com o *Gmail*.

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
// Define os dados do servidor e tipo de conexão
// =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
$mail->IsSMTP(true); // Define que a mensagem será SMTP
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // Endereço do servidor SMTP
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // Usa autenticação SMTP? (opcional)
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Username = 'eu@gmail.com'; // Usuário do servidor SMTP
$mail->Password = 'minhasenha'; // Senha do servidor SMTP

$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->Subject  = "Mensagem Teste"; // Assunto da mensagem
$mail->Body = "Este é o corpo da mensagem de teste, em <b>HTML</b>!  :)";
$mail->AltBody = "Este é o corpo da mensagem de teste, em Texto Plano! \r\n :)";

// Envie a mensagem, verifica se há erros
if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Erro do Mailer: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Mensagem enviada!";
}
```

> Leia também [Atualizando do PHPMailer 5.2 para 6.0](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/UPGRADING.md) em Inglês